# What's the probability that 3 passengers get off on one floor, and 2 get off at a different floor

Tags: probability

Similar to this question:
[Probability Question - An elevator & 5 Passengers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503200/probability-question-an-elevator-5-passengers)

Five people enter an elevator in the basement of a seven story building (ie. the building has a basement, plus floors 1-7).  Each person independently selects one of the seven floors at random.  No new people get on the elevator.

How likely it is that 3 passengers get off on one floor, and the remaining 2 get off on a different floor but also together?

I thought I could do:

(C(5,3) * 7 * C(2,2) * 6)/7^5

= 0.025 or %2.5

Is this correct?

Comment: I see now what you meant sorry I had a typo.  It has been fixed.

Comment: Your answer looks good to me.